# Button Click not working in Angular after applying Ripple.js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular, jquery-plugins

I have a button declared in Angular as below -

```
<div id="btnSearch" class="search_button_right" placement="top" ngbTooltip="Click here to Search">
  <button class="main_serchbtn cursor" type="submit" (click)="Search();"Search</button>
</div>
```

The button click is working fine without fail. In the second step, I included ripple.js library from [here](https://github.com/SirBaaron/ripple-js). As per the document, as soon as I add the `ripple` class to my div, the ripple effect starts working and button click stops working. No errors are logged in Console as well.

**EDIT 1:**
Based on @Sathiyaraj comment, I tried the following without any luck -

```
<div id="btnSearch" class="search_button_right" placement="top" ngbTooltip="Click here to Search">
  <button class="main_serchbtn cursor" type="submit" (ripple-button-click)="Search();"Search</button>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the ng-ripple directive or trying to import directly the ripple's JS into your project?

Sometimes external libraries could conflict with angular and cause the events to not dispatch correctly, try using the ng directive instead

Comment: can you try event bind (ripple-button-click)="Search()" ?

Comment: @FellipeAugustodaSilva, I am adding the ripple.js after installing via npm in my angular-cli.json file. Since I only need to use it at HTML file, don't think I need to import in individual .ts files.

Comment: @Sathiyaraj it didn't work. updated my question.